# Acomodar ArrayList en un GridView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gridview

Que tal amigos, necesito ayuda al crear un `GridView`  en android studio solo que tengo que darle un formato en vertical, bueno me explico mejor.

mi base de datos me trae 12 elemento y lo que yo hago es agregarlo a una `ArrayList<String>` y la lógica que tiene el `GridView` es el resultado en consecutivo y yo lo necesito de esta manera

```
 
    1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9  | 11
    2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 12
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el `grid` me los acomoda de manera consecutiva Ejemplo

```
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  | 5  | 6  
 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un `adapter` para crear el formato como yo lo quiero dejo mi código

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    int contador = 0;
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tickets_gridaviewadapter, null);

    }

    TextView txtPuntoUp, txtPuntoBottom;
    txtPuntoUp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPunto_top);
    txtPuntoBottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPunto_bottom);

    txtPuntoUp.setText(arrayList.get(i));
    txtPuntoBottom.setText(arrayList.get(i+1));

    return view;
}
```

y así genero el arreglo

```
public void ObtenerRegistros()
{
    try {
        Statement statement = conexion().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT vchNombre, iidDispensario FROM catPuntoCarga");
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resultSet.getString("vchNombre"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            listaPuntos.add(resultSet.getString("vchNombre"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

no se si me expliqué bien, pero estaré al pendiente para poder dar mejor explicación a quien la necesite

Comment: pon una imagen de como aparece mejor

Comment: @diegoveloper Ya agregue imagenes de como lo necesito y como me lo organiza

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580573/android-gridview-load-items-vertically

Comment: Mira si puedes implementar la solución de aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580573/android-gridview-load-items-vertically

Answer (score 0):

No testeado

La disposición de los elementos de forma normal, es llenar los elementos en horizontal, al llegar al máximo de `columCount` se llena otra fila

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"    
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="2">
     <TextView
            android:text="Cell 0"
            android:textSize="14dip" />
     <TextView
            android:text="Cell 1"
            android:textSize="14dip" />
     <TextView
            android:text="Cell 2"
            android:textSize="14dip" />
     <TextView
            android:text="Cell 3"
            android:textSize="14dip" />
</GridLayout>
```

Se muestra de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se establece la propiedad `android:orientation="vertical"`, el llenado de los elementos es en vertical al llegar a máximo de `rowCount` se llena la siguiente columna

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"    
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
</GridLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Extraído de [aquí](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/grid-layout/)

Comment: ok pero se podrá hacer lo mismo en un GridView ? porque es lo que estoy utilizando :/

Comment: Mmm parece que me confundido de componente, ya decía yo que no seria tan fácil...